# iOS identifier property deprecated

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

After iOS 7.1, the `identifier` property for `CBPeripheral` has been deprecated. However, `retreivePerihperalsWithIdentifiers` is not deprecated. How can that method be called without using the `identifier` property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a bug of Apple's doc. See code in `CoreBluetooth/CBPeer.h`:

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) NSUUID *identifier NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 7_0);
```

Xcode does not raise warnings for using this property and the code works well in iOS 8 and 9 beta.